# Unable to access resources with access_token : spring boot Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Oauth2 in my existing application.Initially I have added spring security and then tried to add oauth2, After adding configuration I am able to generate access_token but by using access_token i am not able to access resources.

Here is my code:

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/patients").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 1 as enabled from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
}
```

**SecurityOAuth2Configuration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
public class SecurityOAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static String REALM = "CRM_REALM";
    private static final int ONE_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24;
    private static final int THIRTY_DAYS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

**ResourceServer.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/patients/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/patient/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

I have used [this](http://sivatechlab.com/secure-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-part-5/) tutorial for reference.

I am able to get access token using basic auth credentials.

[image]

But when i used the same access token to get resources, it is failing.
[image]

I have added all required tables for oauth.
Is there anything am i missing?

**Update:**

I removed `.and().httpBasic();` and
added @Order(3) in WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter and updated properties file with `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3`

now getting error as

`{
    "timestamp": 1543500350487,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/patient/1/"
}`

**Update 2**

here is my user and authorities schema:

**user**

`+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(50)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(100)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

**authorities**

`+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username  | varchar(50)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| authority | varchar(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

Comment: I think either `.anyRequest().authenticated()` is not required.

Comment: @secretsuperstar,  If i remove it then i am able to access the resources even though i restrict the resources in resourceserver. looks like the resourceserver is not validating the requests at all.

Comment: Can you please show us your User schema / User Role schema tables?

Comment: @EdwinDiaz-Mendez updated question with schema

Comment: Please try `*/patient/**` instead of `/patient` in `antMatchers` in ResourceServer

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri  ,Yes I tried with `*/patient/**` still not working, It looks like resourceserver is getting overridden by securityconfigure, thus nothing is working in resourceserver.

Comment: @vjnan369 : You means your ResouceServer is not working at all? Then you can check it by running your code in debug mode if it is getting executed or not.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, Its method is getting executed, but none of the rules are working inside it, like if i provide `permitAll()` it is not permitting particular end point as securityconfigureradapter making all validation

Comment: `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` provide this on `SecurityConfiguration`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184666/discussion-between-vjnan369-and-jignesh-m-khatri).

Comment: Can you enable debug logging for spring security
add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to `application.properties` and check for **Granted Authorities** in log

Comment: Have posted working solution of your project https://github.com/samidala/spring-oauth2 here.. you may give a try

Answer (score 6):

You should use `hasRole` directly on your antmatcher instead of a string inside the `access()` function. This will evaluate the `hasRole` correctly and correctly determine that the user has access to the requested resource.

This will result in the following code for `ResourceServer.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/patients/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/patient/**").hasRole('USER')
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried that also, still not working, every request is getting validated at WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. If i remove `.anyRequest().authenticated();` in websecurity then i am able to access the resource even though i restrict resources in resourceserver. looks like ResourceServer is not validating the request at all.

Comment: Have you also tried it with `hasAuthority('USER')` insetead of `hasRole()`? (try using both `ROLE_USER` and `USER` in the database column)

Comment: Yes i tried with `hasAuthority('USER')` still not working, but as i told you the requests are not getting validated in resource server. looks like it is overridden by securityconfiguration

Comment: @vjnan369, I validated this in my own, working, spring API with JWT based access and it is an extension, not an overwrite. When you used `hasAuthority('USER')` what was the value in the database for the `USER` role?

Comment: it is `ROLE_USER`

Answer (score 3):

First off, you have two similar methods that modify the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

and

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

Is there a reason they both are there? I do not have this in my config set up.

Furthermore, your query might not be working properly. You should follow some guidelines into how to set up a user service to handle the loaduserbyusername call and the `auth` object with one. As a note: I do not have the same `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` set up as you, **I have mine configured to use a userdetails service, along with a password Encoder** like so.

```
    auth.userDetailsService(securityUserService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoders.userPasswordEncoder());
```

If that doesn't help, here's an alternative way of configuring:

Change the class that extends  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to **only concern itself with the token endpoint.**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/oauth/**").permitAll()
        .and()
    .csrf()
        .disable();
}
```

Now in your `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, have the configuration worry about the stuff in the resource server. Please note, this will work only if your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` configuration is properly loading the Role correctly. As other's have noted, Spring has the prefix `ROLE_`. Which for some reason you are retrieving using a query, and they're authorities.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/api/**")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());

}
```

In my `AuthServerConfig` file I Do not have the following annotations:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
```

I configure the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` differently than the tutorial you followed, mine is the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {

    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}
```

My `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` is still in memory so that's different as well. My `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` is slightly different too, I only add a tokenstore, an enhancer chain (Don't worry about this, it's extra), and an `authenticationManager`

```
    endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might be the way you save/load roles. In spring security there is a default prefix for roles: `ROLE_`. So in your DB (storage) you need to save them as `ROLE_FOO` for example and then you can use `hasRole('FOO')`

I found the same problem here, and my answer seemed to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43568599/4473822

The person that got the issue also had `403 - Forbidden` and saving the roles correctly in the DB solved the problem.

You can also change the default prefix but I would not recommend it unless you want to mess with spring a bit.

Comment: thanks for reply @Tom, I have added the role as ROLE_USER in db. looks like websecurityconfiguration validating the user first because when i add permitAll() for `/content/**` in websecurityconfiguration it is overriding  ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, is it the issue?

Comment: Looks like my ResourceServer not at all authenticating requests

Comment: Your configuration looks very similar to what I am using, the main difference i can find is I have `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on `WebSecurityConfiguration`. It might be that by putting `web-security` on the same level as the `resource-server`, it comes first and never reach your `resource-server` declarations

Comment: tried with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` as well, still not working, i am not encrypting any password or tokens inside database, is there any issue with this according to my code?

Comment: If this was the case you should have got something like `password is incorrect` and not `forbidden`

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code like below in `ResourceServer`:

Have a look at this line:

```
http.anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/patients/**","/patient/**")
```

Since **"/patient/**"**, is not added as part of request matcher, the request is actually was handled by other `configuration`

```
package project.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/patients/**","/patient/**").and().
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("*/patient/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/oauth2-auth-server/?unapproved=69396&moderation-hash=003288035e7decf484494a431a0edff8#comment-69396), I have the same problem, after so much search and try, I solved it by adding the below one.

> After added `@Order(10)` on `OAuth2AuthorizationServer`,`@Order(20)` on `OAuth2ResourceServer`, `@Order(30)` on `SecurityConfig`,

I finally could get resources via an access token. in @Order, Lower values have higher priority, so the reason why we can’t get resources via access token must be that SecurityConfig has higher priority than OAuth2ResourceServer.

So try to add @Order(30) on SecurityConfiguration, @Order(10) on SecurityOAuth2Configuration, and @Order(20) on ResourceServer.

Comment: I had wrong `@Order` (because I merged many tutorials). I wonder why the answer has a down-vote.